# Columns side by side with css grid

Tags: html, css, grid

I am having a problem understanding how CSS grid works.

I want **3** *columns* side by side with a specific ***width*** and ***height***, but there's a gap between each columns.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
}

.left {
  grid-column: 1;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
}

.middle {
  grid-column: 2;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
}

.right {
  grid-column: 3;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="middle">2</div>
  <div class="right">3</div>
</div>
```

In which way I can put away this gap? And if anyone can explain me how to reduce the line of code in css I would be grateful, thanks!

EDIT

I solved in this way

```css
.wrapper{
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.grid-container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    width: 60vw;
    height: 450px;
}



.left{
    background-color: hsl(31, 77%, 52%);
    grid-column: 1;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.middle{
    background-color: hsl(184, 100%, 22%);
    grid-column: 2;
}

.right{
    background-color: hsl(179, 100%, 13%);
    grid-column: 3;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="left">
        <img src="images/icon-sedans.svg" alt="sedans" class="logo">
          <h2 class="text-title">Sedans</h2>
            <div class="main-text">
              Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy. Ideal for cruising in the city 
              or on your next road trip.
            </div>
          <button class="btn">Learn More</button>
      </div>

      <div class="middle">
        <img src="images/icon-suvs.svg" alt="sedans" class="logo">
          <h2 class="text-title">Suvs</h2>
            <div class="main-text">
              Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility. Perfect for your next family vacation 
              and off-road adventures.
            </div>
          <button class="btn">Learn More</button>
      </div>

      <div class="right">
        <img src="images/icon-luxury.svg" alt="sedans" class="logo">
          <h2 class="text-title">Luxury</h2>
            <div class="main-text">
              Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the enhanced comfort of a luxury 
              rental and arrive in style.
            </div>
          <button class="btn">Learn More</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But now what I want to do is to make all of this to be responsive

Comment: There is no gap between columns...

Comment: remove all the width properties and all the grid-column properties then set a fixed width to the container

Comment: CSS grid is not like typical layouts, grid columns/rows are separate from the elements you put inside them, think of it as an invisible element that you can't access directly.

Comment: As Temani says, do not specify any length for your columns width, specify the fractional increment using `grid-template-columns: 1fr, 1fr, 1fr` as you have, then the columns will automatically spread out. 3 elements would be 33% + 33% + 33% to make up the 100% width of the parent. 4 would be 25%, 5 would be 20% and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify your width on your grid parent, remove any static width on your child elements. With the fraction set in `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;` each column will take up a third of the parents width. So if your parent is set to say 80 view width => 80% of the view port, then your columns will spread out over a third of that width each.

If you have had 4 items each set to 1fr, then they would take up 25%, 5 would take up 20%, basically => **number of children elements**/**parents width**.

```css
.grid-container {
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 0;
  width: 80vw;
}

.left>ul {
  height: 80%;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: space-between;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.middle {
  padding: 5px;
  grid-column: 2;
  border: red solid 1px;
}

.middle span {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: start;
  padding: 5px;
  grid-column: 2;
  background: lightblue;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.right {
  grid-column: 3;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.row {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: start;
  background: #EEE;
}

.right div:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: #a2a2a2;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="left">Here is some content for column 1 with list items
    <ul>
      <li>
        display: flex
      </li>
      <li>
        flex-direction: column
      </li>
      <li>
        justify-content: space-around
      </li>
      <li>
        align-items: flex-start
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <span>This is inside a span tag</span>
    <span>Parent has flex direction of column</span>
    <span>Justify Content set at start</span>
    <span>this is inside a span tag</span> More content for column 2. it is a bit longer than the first textual content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum viverra pulvinar tincidunt. Nam consequat metus et cursus auctor.
    Suspendisse posuere sem ut tortor lacinia, nec tempor turpis ultrices. Sed vitae gravida orci.</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="row">
      <h3>Row</h3>
      <h3>Space</h3>
      <h3>Between</h3>
    </div>
    <span>Parents flex <span style="background: pink;">flex-direction </span> and <span style="background: pink;">display-flex</span> <b>flex</b> and <b>column</b></span></span>
    <span>Parents flex <span style="background: pink;">justify-content</span> is set to <b>space-around</b></span>
    <div>Good ole text-align: center... Vestibulum viverra pulvinar tincidunt. Nam consequat metus et cursus auctor. Suspendisse posuere sem ut tortor lacinia, nec tempor turpis ultrices.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example of *vertically* centering text with **flex-direction** set to ***column***.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: calc(200px - 1rem);
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Vertically centering using flex.
    <br><br> Justify content when parents flex-direction is set to column, will center content vertically.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! Now I'm trying to vertically centering columns using flexbox but it doesn't work with grid. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to center the content within the columns or the main grid display?

Comment: I added some flex properties on the children and their children to show you some examples. Also the main `grid-container` content is set to `margin: 0 auto;` to center it on the page. Best if viewed in full page to get the idea.

Comment: On display flex with a flex-direction set to column, your justify-content will be the centering vertically

Answer (score 1):

You can simply specify the widths that you need in the `grid-template-columns` property. There is no gap visible between columns.

If you want the red borders you can specify a common class for those divs and just do it once.

```css
.grid-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 300px 300px 300px;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    column-gap: 0;
    height: 500px;
}
.left{
    border: 1px solid red;  
}

.middle{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.right{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="left">1</div>
    <div class="middle">2</div>
    <div class="right">3</div>
  </div>
```